# Sequence converging to a

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, real-numbers

Given a sequence of real numbers $a_n$ ($n \in \Bbb{N}$) that converges to $a \in \Bbb{R}$, show that the sequence $b_n$ ($n \in \Bbb{N}$) also converges to 
$a$.

$$b_n=\frac{1}{n}(a_1+a_2+a_3+...+a_n)$$

I would be grateful for any tips, I have no idea where to look for sequences converging to sequences(?) - or is only $a_n$ a sequence and $a$ is not? I thought about the opposite, but couldn't help myself that way either ("if $b_n$ converges to $a$, does $a_n$ converge to $a$?"). I'd be grateful for any solutions to similar problems, that won't give away the solution - which I have in my book. I'd still like to understand it without looking that up though.

Comment: Also, the standard terminology is that $a_n$ converges **to** $a$, not against $a$.

Comment: Thanks, English is not my first language, the direct German translation would be as  I wrote it above - so that help alot for further questions.